# Code hangs when trying to get the response code

Tags: java, url, web-crawler, ping, http-response-codes

I am trying to crawl 300,000 URLs. However, somewhere in the middle the code hangs when trying to retrieve the response code from a URL. I am not sure what is going wrong since a connection is being established but the problem is occurring after that. Any suggestions/pointers will be greatly appreciated. Also, is there any way to ping a website for a certain time period and if it's not responding just proceed to the next one?

I have modified the code as per the suggestions having set the read time out and the request property as suggested.However, even now the code is unable to obtain the response code!

Here is my modified code snippet:

```
URL url=null;

try
{
    Thread.sleep(8000);
}
catch (InterruptedException e1)
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

try
{
    //urlToBeCrawled comes from the database
    url=new URL(urlToBeCrawled);
}
catch (MalformedURLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    //The code is in a loop,so the use of continue.I apologize for putting code in the catch block.
    continue;
}
HttpURLConnection huc=null;
try
{
    huc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try
{
   //Added the request property
    huc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
    huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

}
catch (ProtocolException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

huc.setConnectTimeout(1000);
try
{
    huc.connect();

}
catch (IOException e)
{

    e.printStackTrace();
    continue;
}

int responseCode=0;
try
{
    //Sets the read timeout
    huc.setReadTimeout(15000);
    //Code hangs here for some URL which is random in each run
    responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();

}
catch (IOException e)
{
    huc.disconnect();

    e.printStackTrace();
    continue;
}
if (responseCode!=200)
{
    huc.disconnect();
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really should be done using multi-threading. **Especially** if you are attempting 300,000 URLs. I prefer the [thread-pool approach](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for this.

Second, you will really benefit better from a more robust HTTP client such as the apache commons http client as it can better set the user-agent. Whereas the most JRE's will not allow you to modify the user-agent using the `HttpURLConnection` class (they force it to your JDK version, eg: `Java/1.6.0_13` will be your user-agent.) There are tricks to change this by adjusting the system property but I have never seen that actually work. Again go just go with Apache Commons HTTP library, you won't regret it.

Finally you need a good http debugger to deal with this ultimately, You can use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), and just [setup a java proxy to point to fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp) (scroll to the part about Java).

Answer (score 1):

A server is holding the connection open but also is not responding.  It may even be detecting that you're spidering their site and the firewall or anti-DDOS tools are intentionally trying to confuse you.  Be sure you set a user-agent (some servers will get angry if you don't).  Also, set a read timeout so that if it fails to read after awhile, it'll give up:

```
huc.setReadTimeout(15000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you point me towards a resource which describes how to set up a user agent?

Comment: @collegian - it is just a request header: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43

Comment: `huc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");`

Comment: I believe readTimeout will only work if an actual connection is made and bytes can begin streaming. You will need to set a a lower connection timeout as well. (eg: `setConnectTimeout(int timeout)`)